# What is the condition to extract a pointwise convergence subsequence from a weakly convergent sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose I have a reflexive banach space $X$, and I have a weakly convergent sequence $f_n$,

What is the condition to extract a pointwise strong convergence subsequence from a weakly convergent sequence?

Actually I want to use Fatou's lemma to conclude that the sequence of function is weakly lower semi cts after integrating i.e. $\int f <\liminf \int f_n $  .

Thanks

Comment: So $X$ is obviously a space of functions. Can you give more information on $X$? For instance this is true in some Sobolev spaces by Rellich's compactness theorem.

Comment: What if $X$=$W^{1,2}$? May i embed  $W^{1,2}$ into $C$?

Comment: Over what domains are you working (bounded, smooth, etc.)? What is $C$?

Comment: You may assume it is a bdd open domain and$C$ is the space of cts functions